# How to draw ReLU function

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw functions (like ReLU) that have different function values for different domains.

ReLU is defined as;

f(x)=0 for x<0
f(x)=x for x>=0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19510/defining-a-piecewise-function-for-pgfplots

Answer (score 6):

I've adapted hugovdberg's answer to: [How can I produce such a graph of my piecewise function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166481/how-can-i-produce-such-a-graph-of-my-piecewise-function?rq=1)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-3:5,
        ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=-3:0] {0};
        \addplot+[mark=none,red,domain=0:5] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, another question on your answer. How can I make the values of function shown from zero?

Comment: @guest345 What does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option, taking advantage of the definition of `>` and `<` as boolean operators in pgfplots. It has the advantage to define one single function (hence no legend issues, style is easier to define, etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    domain=-3:5,
    ]
    \addplot {(x>=0)*x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 1):

As [JM114516](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334653/95441) already stated in his answer, the solution from [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334591/95441) is sub-optimal, because drawing two lines for one line has several disadvantages.

Here I present a solution that is a bit more general, i.e. it isn't restricted that one side of the piecewise function is zero, by using the `ifthenelse` operator. And to show the "generality" of this solution I have used `x^2` for the `then` part instead of just `0` which gives the solution guest345 was asking for.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=-3:5,
        ]
            \addplot {
                ifthenelse(
                    x<0,        % if
                    x^2,        % then
                    x           % else
                )
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]